# Interface Fatal Error

Tags: php, symfony, zend-framework2, doctrine

So this is my code on my newly created page inside the Entity folder...

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Application\Entity\Categories;
use PerfectWeb\Core\Interfaces\Routable;
use Application\Mapper\Injector;
use PerfectWeb\Core\Traits;
use PerfectWeb\Core\View\Helper\Object;
use PerfectWeb\Core\Utils\Slug;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class VodCategory extends Categories implements 
Entity\Interfaces\Categories, Routable
{

    function getRoute($type = Object::ROUTE_TYPE_VIEW)
    {
        return 'category/categories';
    }

    function getRouteParams()
    {
        return
            [
            Injector::CATEGORY => $this->getID(),
            'slug' => Slug::getSlug($this->getSlug()),
            ];
    }
}
```

And this is my `category.php` file:

```
<?php

namespace Application\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use PerfectWeb\Core\Traits;

/**
 * Categories
 * @ORM\Table(name="categories")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Categories
{

    use Traits\Entity;
    use Traits\User;
    use Traits\Name;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", nullable=false, unique=false)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Categories", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true, onDelete="SET NULL")
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $parent = null;

    /**
     * @var \Application\Entity\User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="categories")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Videos\Entity\Video", mappedBy="category", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY"))
     *
     */
    protected $videos;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="entity", type="string", nullable=true, unique=false)
     */
    protected $entity;

    /**
     *
     * construct function for array collection
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->videos = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getVideos()
    {
        return $this->videos;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $videos
     */
    public function setVideos($videos)
    {
        $this->videos = $videos;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Get parent
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getParent()
    {
        return $this->parent;
    }

    /**
     * Set parent
     *
     * @param integer $parent
     * @return Categories
     */
    public function setParent($parent)
    {
        $this->parent = $parent;
        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->getName();
    }
}
```

the first bit of code gives me an error:

> Fatal Error Interface 'Categories\Entity\Interfaces\Categories' not found in /var/www/html/camclients/module/Videos/src/Videos/Entity/VodCategory.php

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your Entity don't found `Entity\Interfaces\Categories` Interface.
Where is your Interface? I Think you forgot `Application\ ` before the interface namespace

Comment: I fixed my interface error ..by removing it and just implementing routable but my code does not do what its supposed to ...i have a table of thumbnails for videos and each division has a title for the video and the category for that video ..when some1 clicks the category name it has to make a list of categories and videos inside the categories

Comment: @DLMike That is a new question. You should close this question and post a new question if you want help with the next issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You implement the interface `Entity\Interfaces\Categories` inside your category class but this interface cannot be found.
You should have an interface in that namespace (and folder) or you should point to the correct location (the folder/namespace where your interface is located).

If your interface exists then it is probably a namespace issue like @doydoy44 suggested in the comment. Then make sure that the `namespace` declaration and file location of your interface are correct.